# Shimano 105 r7000 front derailleur hard and clunky shifting, shifter harder to shift

Tags: road-bike, shimano, derailleur, repair

A total newbie to DIY bike repair here, and my Shimano 105 r7000 FD is shifting really harshly after a wash. Washed it with dish soap plus water solution, however I did not give the FD any specific attention since it's a new bike and the FD looked clean, everything was gently rinsed. As I was fiddling with the levers trying to get my chain back on the bike, noticed that the FD shift lever has a LOT more resistance post-wash, it's much harder to shift up or down, and in the video of the shifting action you can see there are three clicks of the shifter possible when downshifting. I'm thinking this a lubrication issue (can i re-lube this with chain lube?) or did I cock up a brand new FD on a brand new bike??? Please be easy on me, still learning and growing as a DIY-er.
Thank you for reading and commenting.
Have a good day

[imgur link with the FD mechanism video](https://imgur.com/a/Y1EoBCz).

Comment: I don't think that it has to do with lack of grease in the derailleur, I would rather guess it has to do with wrong adjustment/cable tension or the cable not running freely internally. I run a mechanical 105 (though it is R5800) and I'm pretty sure the first click (trim) moves the derailleur a lot more than yours does, second click already shifts on the small chainring, yours seems to have position "extra"?

Comment: Just a hint: it could be the FD, the cable, or the shifter. Personally, i'd start checking the cable. Not least because it's the least expensive.

Comment: Try moving the derailleur cage by hand. Does it move freely? With the shifter in the small ring position and manually pushing the derailleur to the big ring position, you can operate the cable a little. Does that feel smooth?